# Realm's RealmChangeListener as anonymous class does not get called every time

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to solve an issue about Realm's RealmChangeListener added as anonymous class. The problem is, that sometimes it gets called, but sometimes not. However, if class implements RealmChangeListener and to query is added as `this`, everything works fine.

In following example, when I open the app, 4 requests are made to local repository to load data from database at the same time. So getUsers method is called 4 times, each time with different `User.Type` value. However, most of the time (80%) `RealmChangeListener` is called just once.

**This is not working**

```
public class Repo {

    Reaml mRealm;

    public Repo(@Inject Realm realm){
        this.mReal = realm;
    }

    public void getUsers(User.Type type, Callbacks callbacks){
        mRealm.where(User.class)
            .equalTo("type", type.name())
            .findAllSortedAsync("firstName", Sort.ASCENDING)
            .addChangeListener(new new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<User>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChange(RealmResults<User> element) {
                    if (element.isLoaded()) {
                        Log.d("%s users are loaded", type.name());
                        callbacks.onUsersLoaded(element);
                        element.removeChangeListener(this);
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

However, if `Repo` class implements RealmChangeListener and I pass it to RealmResults as `this` reference, it get called properly, 4 times.

**This is working!**

```
public class Repo implements RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<User>>{

    Reaml mRealm;

    public Repo(@Inject Realm realm){
        this.mReal = realm;
    }

    public void getUsers(User.Type type, Callbacks callbacks){
        mRealm.where(User.class)
            .equalTo("type", type.name())
            .findAllSortedAsync("firstName", Sort.ASCENDING)
            .addChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<User> element) {
        if (element.isLoaded()) {
            Log.d("Users are loaded from THIS");
            callbacks.onUsersLoaded(element);
            element.removeChangeListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions where could be a problem and how could I solve that ? I would like to use anonymous class instead of reference to `this`. 
I was trying to search for solution on SO, Realm's documentation, GitHub, but no success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since the `mRealm` is a member of `Repo`, I guess your `Repo` instance gets GCed so the listener won't be called anymore. The second "working" example might have leaks. Please check how does the life cycle look like for the `Repo` instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply @beeender ! I tried to put a log into `finalize` method, but it never gets called. Do you you have any suggestion how else could I check the lifecycle ? 
**btw**
Repo instance is member of presenter and presenter is a member of a fragment.
Fragments are in ViewPager and each fragment has its own presenter.

Comment: Uh, i missed this :) `.findAllSortedAsync("firstName", Sort.ASCENDING)` returns an anonymous `RealmResults` which will be GCed since no one is holding a ref to it. After it gets GCed, the relevant listener will be GCed as well. So, just have a `RealmResults mResults` as a member var for your `Repo` object.

Comment: I tried that before, but same results :/
`final RealmResults<User> result = mRealm....`

Comment: An other thing, even there are 4 requests to change the Realm db (4 times `commitTransaction()` called), it doesn't necessarily mean the listener will be called 4 times. The listener is guaranteed to be be called to reflect the latest database changes.

Comment: Well, it wasn't changing state of Realm db, as it was just query, not insert nor update. However, thanks for pointing out about GC, that was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

answer is pretty easy and as **@beeender** pointed out, **results got GCed**. I didn't realize that even if I had a local variable `final RealmResults<User> result` to which I was assigning result of `. findAllSortedAsync`, it got GCed almost immediately after method body was executed.

**So, the solution is to change `RealmResults<User> result` from local variable to instance variable.**